# Java two-dimensional-arrays: Rectangle from A & B letters in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I got the task to complete a code by **only on row, where I should define a two-dimensional array with the correct type and size**. The code prints out a rectangle, consisting of A-s on the edges and B-s on the inside. I got the code working, my problem is however that I do not understand why does it work with any numbers > 7 for both dimensions. It doesn't matter if I put 8,9 or 1854 and 8782, it still works...

```
        int breite = 6;
        int hoehe = 3;
        char[][] array = new char [8][9];
        for(int i = 0; i <= (hoehe+1); i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j <= (breite+1); j++) {
                if((i == 0 || j == 0) || ( i == (hoehe+1) || j == (breite+1))) {
                    System.out.print("A");
                    array[j][i] = 'A';
                }
                else {
                    System.out.print("B");
                    array[j][i] = 'B';
                }
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
```

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: Please state your question more clearly.

Comment: The question is, why do you expect it to don't work?

Comment: If your task is to `define a two-dimensional array in only one row`, as you state, then you are already doing way too much. Just declare the array... `char[][] array = new char[breite][hoehe];` and be done...

Comment: If you size the array bigger than you need, it will waste memory, but still work. If you size the array too small, you will get an error (as soon as you access something that is now out of bounds).